# How to select correct column from treeview after using focus within tkinter

Tags: python, dataframe, tkinter

I have an issue where I get the current record/row in a treeview but then fail to get the correct columns when trying to update the record for given columns at the end of record/row

Function I call in a Tkinter button to update a record

```
# Update Records
def update_record():
    # Grab record number
    selected = my_tree.focus()
    # Update Record
    my_tree.item(selected, text="", values=(fl_spinbox.get(), cnt_entry.get(),))
    # Clear entry boxes
    fl_spinbox.delete(0, END)
    cnt_entry.delete(0, END)
```

My issue is that I have 5 columns that come before the 2 columns `fenceLabel` & `Comment` represented by the following `fl_spinbox`, `cnt_entry` entry boxes where the other 5 columns are not to be modified by the user so I don't provide entry boxes.

Currently, this function works but updates/inputs the first 2 column values with entry box values as opposed to referencing the 2 columns at the end of the treeview. I had thought that `fl.spinbox.get()` & `cnt_entry.get()` would reference them correctly.

Should I be doing something else to reference the column directly?